# Count Number of occurrences SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences separate log messages appears per client

My table is in this structure

```
EventTime - Logmessage - HostName -  Client
```

This query gives me a number of logs for each client:

```
 SELECT Count([Log Message]) AS Count
  ,[Client]
 FROM [test1].[dbo].[logs_test]
 Group By Client
```

How would I go down into a lower level and get the number of times a log appears per client? The output I'm looking to achieve is something like the below

```
Log Message    Count  Client

NON ATTEMPT    12     TestClient
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Would that work for you? SELECT Count(1) AS Count
  ,[Client]
,[LogMessage]
 FROM [test1].[dbo].[logs_test]
 Group By Client, LogMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change what you are counting and add another level to your grouping...

```
 SELECT LogMessage
  , Count(EventTime) AS Count
  , Client
 FROM [test1].[dbo].[logs_test]
 Group By Client, LogMessage
```

Comment: i was truncating the column to only show 5 chars, but its fine once i show the whole log and sort by logs > 10 it sorts out all the fluff. Thanks!